# Imported eclipse project error after updating android sdk

Tags: android

After updating android sdk, encounter a confused error when building my project.

It is a imported eclipse project, what I did is installed SDK 26 and build-tools 26, uninstalled old SDK 15-18 and build-tools 25.0.2.

I try to reinstall these things, but not work.

Here is the error message:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidTarget(AndroidJpsUtil.java:404)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidJpsUtil.java:480)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.builder.AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.computeRootDescriptors(AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.addRoots(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:72)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.<init>(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:267)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$$Lambda$4/71020844.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$$Lambda$2/1522311648.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Reinstall IDEA 2017.1 and it works, seems like something wrong with IDEA 2017.2 about imported Eclipse android project.

Comment: @asozcan i'm using JDK 1.8 and IDEA 2017.2. I get the same error. I don't have the 2017.1 version. But I tried 2016.2 and got a completely different error `Error:Android Pre Dex: [cordova-2.3.0.jar] Failed to load dx.jar`. I've spent at least 8 work hours researching this problem with no success. One more thing, I didn't import the project. I pulled from a git repo.

Comment: seems 2017.2 causing problem, downgrade your version or copy files <ANDROID_SDK>/tools/lib/annotations-25.3.2.jar & common-25.3.2.jar to <IDEA_DIR>/lib/ , then restart IDEA, problem solved. it's also resolved with 2017.2.2 RC, just fyi.